# Can I change LXDE default file browser to

Tags: nautilus, lxde, filemanager, pcmanfm

I have to use LXDE as my DE because of the age of my computer/hardware, and I like it a lot, but I also like using Nautilus as my File Manager (it appears to have more options) for basic file browsing.

If I can I would like to change my default file manager from pcmanfm to Nautilus. I know this is possible, but the things I have seen, nothing seems to work the way I want it to.

Thanks!

Comment: Please expand on "I know this is possible, but the things I have seen, nothing seems to work the way I want it to."

Answer (score 0):

Look [Manual Method](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DefaultFileManager#Manual_Method) section of Ubuntu Documentation. 
Probably you should only edit `~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` file. Add two lines:

```
inode/directory=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
x-directory/normal=nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
```

If there already is line as

```
inode/directory=pcmanfm.desktop
```

just remove it.

Comment: didn't work for me :(